# Change indexes of an array to a JavaScript string

Tags: javascript

Hello js sabers I am trying to see if it is possible to create or modify an array:

```js
    [
        {title: "METER_STATE", elements: [
            {combo: "a", id: 1},
            {combo: "b", id: 2},
            {combo: "c", id: 3},
        ]},
        {title: "REGULATOR_STATE", elements: [
            {combo: "aa", id: 1},
            {combo: "bb", id: 2},
            {combo: "cc", id: 3},
        ]},
        {title: "ACTIVITY_TYPE", elements: [
            {combo: "aaa", id: 1},
            {combo: "bbb", id: 2},
            {combo: "cccc", id: 3},
        ]}
    ]
```

What I am trying to do is modify that instead of having numerical indexes (0,1,2 according to the example) they are for example (STATUS_MEDIDOR, STATUS_REGULATOR and TYPE_ACTIVITY) I do not know if it is possible that is why I go with you, I have investigated in google but i don't see anything clear, searched like "replace array index to any javascript phrase" but didn't find something to really help me. The reason for this is that I am from an xml view reading each item in the following way "fixname/0/items" so I had the doubt that instead of using the indexes I could use something else

Does anyone know about it?

Beforehand thank you very much

Comment: Flagging as off-topic because it's not in english.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because does not conform to posting guidelines

Answer (score 1):

To turn an array (many things) into an object (one thing), use `reduce`. Since there's a mapping between array positions and keys in the target object, make that mapping explicit and use it in the reduce.

```js
const array = [
        {titulo:"ESTADO_MEDIDOR", items:[
            {combo: "a", id: 1},
            {combo: "b", id: 2},
            {combo: "c", id: 3},
        ]},
        {titulo:"ESTADO_REGULADOR", items:[
            {combo: "aa", id: 1},
            {combo: "bb", id: 2},
            {combo: "cc", id: 3},
        ]},
        {titulo:"TIPO_ACTIVIDAD", items:[
            {combo: "aaa", id: 1},
            {combo: "bbb", id: 2},
            {combo: "cccc", id: 3},
        ]}
    ]

const keyFromTitle = title => 'STATUS_' + title.split('_')[1]
const result = array.reduce((acc, el, index) => {
  acc[keyFromTitle(el.titulo)] = el
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: cool thaks!, but it not possible to mantain the array ? just changing the index of each elemnt of the array ??

Comment: @NaotoAmari - I'm not sure if I understand. Maybe you're asking about requiring the mapping between indices and the keys?  If the key can be derived from the object in the array, then we can skip the hard-coded index. I've edited to demonstrate